# Add unique arrays to object and make sure they are different

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to have an object made of arrays containing integers as indicators used by another method. Each array of integers have to be different, but my function has to randomly create them and while adding a new array make sure that it doesn't exist already, but at the same time a specific amount of arrays have to be added.

Lets say I want an object that look like this:

```
arr = { 
  0: [0,0],
  1: [0,1],
  2: [1,1],
  3: [1,0]
}
```

The above object can be in different order of course, depending on the random aspect of below `Math.random`.
That's the code I have:

```
let arrayOfPositions = [];
let i = 0;
let position = [];

do {
  let randX = Math.round(Math.random());
  let randY = Math.round(Math.random());
  position = [randX, randY];
  arrayOfPositions[i] = position;
  i++;
}

while (arrayOfPositions.length < 4 );
```

There's something missing in my while condtition to check if the `position` already exist in the `arrayOfPositions`. I tried `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` but it then always stopped after first array added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and [lastIndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) while searching for the index of an Object (an Array in this case) and both of them only work for [primitives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive).

You can either [stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) the values (1) or check for the inner Array values for equality (2).

(1) is a bit tricky and slow, because you'd have to stringify both the original array value (`arrayOfPositions`), the new `position` you're trying to add and then you can use `indexOf` and its derivatives. So I'm going to skip that one.

For (2) I'd change the code a little bit and assume you can use [ES6 Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) as you're using `let`:

```
let positions = []
do {
  const position = createUniquePos(positions)
  positions.push(position)
}
while (positions.length < 4)

function createUniquePos(positions) {
  const x = Math.round(Math.random())
  const y = Math.round(Math.random())
  // here we check if that pair already exists in the array
  return positions.find( pos => pos[0] === x && pos[1] === y )
    // if it does exist, then we do another attempt with recursion
    ? createUniquePos(positions)
    // if it doesn't, then we return the unique position
    : [x, y]
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you for the clear explanation of where the problem was. Appreciated.

Comment: Just one question though, how can I expand on this if the arrays can change from two values to more? Like [0,0] at the start and [0,0,0,0,0,0,0] later on.

Comment: Not sure if I'm following, could you provide a full resulting array?

Answer (score -1):

```
const positionSet = new Set();
while(positionSet.size < 4){
  const randX = Math.round(Math.random());
  const randY = Math.round(Math.random());
  const position = [randX, randY];
  positionSet.add(position);
}
```

A set is unique, so if you add the same value, then it will just be ignored.

If you want to use array function like `map`, `filter` or `reduce`, then you can do `Array.from(positionSet);` or if you don't have ES7, you can write `Array.prototype.slice.call(positionSet);`

Comment: You are right, they worked differently in TypeScript, but it works to check for `has` though with objects